# error on install pthread php xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, pthreads

I'm try to install pthread on Windows. I download the package and move

- `php_pthreads.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- `php_pthreadVC2.dll` to `C:\xampp\apache\bin`
- `php_pthreadVC2.dll` to `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- `php_pthreadVC2.dll` to `C:\Windowns\System32`
- `php_pthreadVC2.dll` to `C:\xampp\apache\bin`

add to php.ini

```
extension = php_pthreads.dll
```

after restarting apache, the following error occurs:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pthreads: Unable to initialize
>   module\nModule compiled with module API=20151012\nPHP    compiled with
>   module API=20160303\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line
>   0

Help me please!!!!

Comment: Your extensions to work properly have to have the same date/version number as the PHP module - you have `20151012` and `20160303`.

Comment: Same issue i am facing . I have xampp version 3.2.4 and php version is 7.4